# Minimal value of maximum number and Maximal value of minimum number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's a problem my Discrete mathematics professor challenged us to solve regarding proving the existence of a minimal value of a maximum number of objects and Maximal value of minimum number of objects. The problem goes like this...

Let n and k be natural numbers.
n students walk into k empty classrooms. Some classrooms might still be empty, because no
students entered them, but we know every student walked into one of the classrooms. Each classroom
has some nonnegative number of students.
Let M denote the maximal number of students in one classroom.
Let m denote the minimal number of students in one classroom.
The numbers M and m may be different for different distributions of students into classrooms.

For example suppose there are 3 students and 3 classrooms.
If all 3 students walk into one room then M = 3 and m = 0.
If 2 students walk into one room and the 3rd student walks into room then M = 2 and m = 0
If each student walks into a different room then M = 1 and m = 1.

I know that in the above example the minimal value of M is 1 and maximal value of m is 1.
In general the answer will depend on n and k, i just can't figure it out.

EDIT:
The answer could be expressed mathematically as max m=⌊n/k⌋ and min M=⌈n/k⌉ as answered by user calvin Lin. But could someone provide a prove for that answer ?

Comment: Note that $m$ and $M$ can be at most $1$ apart.

Comment: Don, you mean that max of m and the min of M are at most 1 apart?

Comment: Don, how did you come up with that?

Comment: To find minimum of $M$. Put all students into one room then calculate how many you can send into other rooms so that the starting room had at least the same number of students as any other room. Sounds like you need to divide evenly between $k$ rooms, right? So divide and round up as you cannot have fraction of a student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For the general case, describe in words what you think these values must be, and explain why these hold. That will help you figure out the proof.

The mathematical formula for the answer is:

> $ \max m = \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$ and $ \min M = \lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil$.

Comment: Can you help me with the proof maybe? No one was able to prove it in the class.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Let's say you have $n = 100$ students in $k = 3$ classrooms. Can you explain why there is one classroom with at least 33 students? Can you explain why there is one classroom with at most 34 students?

Comment: No, i cannot explain none of that to be honest. That's what im struggling with, i can come up with answer intuitively but cannot form the proof, so I came asking here. What would a good proof for such a problem be? say in case of a test or exam.

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction.